# Add multiple checkmark to cell in different sections and save their state in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, row, checkmark

In my app i have 5 sections with some data in it. what i want is to checkmark lets say 2 cell in section 1, then 3 cell in section 2 and so on at a time. The multiple selection in different sections in working and whatever cell is being checkmarked in that cell i have a label title which i am adding and storing in userdefaults because that title i need to show in previous screen. Now when i selected 2 cells from section 1, 2 cell from section 2 and go back then only latest selection cell title is showing in previous screen which is wrong it should show 4 titles with comma seperated which code i have written in previous screen. Dont know what to do

My code:-

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allAssetCell", for: indexPath) as! AllAssetCell

        var mainArr = [SymName]()

        if indexPath.section == digitalIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filtereddigitalArr : digitalArr
        }
        else if indexPath.section == forexIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filteredforexArr : forexArr
        }
        else if indexPath.section == stocksIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filteredstocksArr : stocksArr
        }
        else if indexPath.section == cryptoIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filteredcryptoArr : cryptoArr
        }
        else if indexPath.section == commoditiesIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filteredcommoditiesArr : commoditiesArr
        }
        else if indexPath.section == etfIndex
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? filteredetfArr : etfArr
        }
        else
        {
            mainArr = isSearch ? (filtereddigitalArr + filteredforexArr + filteredstocksArr + filteredcryptoArr + filteredcommoditiesArr + filteredetfArr) : (digitalArr + forexArr + stocksArr + cryptoArr + commoditiesArr + etfArr)
        }

        cell.lblSymbolsName.text = mainArr[indexPath.row].name
        cell.accessoryType = mainArr[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        var mainArr = [SymName]()
        var filteredMainArr = [SymName]()

        if indexPath.section == digitalIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filtereddigitalArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filtereddigitalArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                digitalArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = digitalArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else if indexPath.section == forexIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filteredforexArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredforexArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                forexArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = forexArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else if indexPath.section == stocksIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filteredstocksArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredstocksArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stocksArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = stocksArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else if indexPath.section == cryptoIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filteredcryptoArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredcryptoArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cryptoArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = cryptoArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else if indexPath.section == commoditiesIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filteredcommoditiesArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredcommoditiesArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                commoditiesArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = commoditiesArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else if indexPath.section == etfIndex
        {
            if isSearch
            {
                filteredetfArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredetfArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                etfArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = etfArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mainArr = digitalArr + forexArr + stocksArr + cryptoArr + commoditiesArr + etfArr
            filteredMainArr = filtereddigitalArr + filteredforexArr + filteredstocksArr + filteredcryptoArr + filteredcommoditiesArr + filteredetfArr

            if isSearch
            {
                filteredMainArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = filteredMainArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mainArr[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
                let selectedNames = mainArr.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
                UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedNames, forKey: "selectedNames")

                if selectedNames.count > 0
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: selectedNames)
                }
                else
                {
                    ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.saveAssetTypeTextUserDefaults(arr: ["All Assets"])
                }
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
```

Comment: Is using UserDefaults to send data between view controllers really a good solution, shouldn't you send data directly between them instead? Maybe use the delegate pattern here? Maybe you could make your code clearer by not having so many sections in the posted code. Perhaps trim it down to code for 2 sections to make the code clearer but still comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare these two variables outside of the didSelect method

```
var mainArr = [SymName]()
var filteredMainArr = [SymName]()
```

Because when you select a cell, it creates new array and previous is discarded.